# Как изменить шаблон WooCommerce на свой

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть онлайн магазин, сделан на WordPress. Почти все шаблоны идут от WooCommerce. Сейчас мне нужно сделать изменения на этом шаблоне. Есть способ не залезть в плагины? Мне нужно делать все изменения в папке themes.

Нужно изменить страницу корзины, страницу товара и страницу каталога товаров.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы внесёте изменения в плагин, они пропадут при обновлении. Все изменения надо делать в [дочерней теме](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

В корне дочерней темы создаёте папку woocommerce и в неё копируете только нужные шаблоны из папки `templates` плагина, сохраняя структуру подпапок. Там шаблоны можно править, изменения останутся после обновления тем и плагинов.

Примеры отображения путей:
`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` => `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`
`/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php` => `wp-content/themes/my-themes/woocommerce/single-product/price.php`

P.S. Следуя комментариям ниже:

Добавьте в functions.php своей темы поддержку WooCommerce:

```
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
```

Подробнее о структуре шаблонов WooCommerce [здесь](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: я бы еще добавил, что в теме должна быть включена поддержка woocommerce.-  add_theme_support('woocommerce' ); add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
   add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

Comment: Кстати да,  у него своя тема и наверняка поддержка не включена.

Comment: @KAGGDesign думаю стоит добавить ссылку на ман https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev спасибо, добавил

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо, добавил